# stop script or loop after first match without using exit;

Tags: php, while-loop, exit, exit-code

no idea how to ask this question... the problem is that I need to stop the loop from runing if `if ($current[$id][$i]['item'] == '')` is true, so whatever the script needs to do or in this case echo, don't get repeated 15 times.

If using `exit;` the whole page will stop to render, so, any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

If the question is not clear enough don't hesitate to ask using the comments, I will more than happy to clarify any doubts.

```
$i=1; 
while($i<=15) { 
    if ($current[$id][$i]['item'] == '') { 
        echo 'Done!.';
        //do something
    } 
    $a++; 
}
```

Comment: Hate to *break* it to you, but this stuff is simple!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

```
$i=1; 
while($i<=15) { 
    if ($current[$id][$i]['item'] == '') { 
        echo 'Done!.';
        break;
    } 
    $i++;  //<- that should probably be $i instead of $a?
}
```

Comment: @user983248 actually I just slightly edited the post, the credit for answer goes to Gryphius

Answer (score 3):

How about using the [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) control structure?

Answer (score 2):

You need to **break**. Also, your current loop is endless and will therefore time-out. Presumably you meant to increment `$i`, not `$a`.

```
$i=1; 
while($i<=15) { 
    if ($current[$id][$i]['item'] == '') { 
        echo 'Done!.';
        break; //<-- terminate loop
    } 
    $a++; //<-- shouldn't this be $i++?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only 2 ways to break a loop... using `exit;` and `break;`....

`break;` is what you want it will exit the loop and continue execution, exit will end the script.

Answer (score -1):

```
$i=1; 
while($i<=15) { 
    if ($current[$id][$i]['item'] == '') { 
        echo 'Done!.';
        break;  //   or you can make value of $i = 20;
    } 
    $a++; 
}
```

Comment: While this works, I wouldn't do that - this may lead to all sorts of problems if the upper limit for `$i` changes. That's why there's the `break` keyword.

Comment: Agreed - it will work, but there's no case for using this technique over `break` and could have side-effects.

Comment: @Utkanos first i thought the he need to do it in js that's why I posted this